# Replace all occurences of a word in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Is there no easy way to replace all occurrences of a (whole) word in a string? I am using this currently and it is not very elegant:

```
public static String replace(String input, String toReplace, 
                           String replacement){
    if(input==null) throw new NullPointerException();
    input = input.replace(" "+toReplace+" ", " "+replacement+" ");
    input = input.replaceAll("^"+toReplace+" ", replacement+" ");
    input = input.replaceAll(" "+toReplace+"$", " "+replacement);
    return input;
}
```

Also, the regular expression `"^"+toReplace+" "` is not regex safe. For example: when it might contain a character like `[` or `(` etc.

**Edit:**

Any reasons why this code:

```
public static String replace(String input, String toReplace, 
                           String replacement){
    if(input==null) throw new NullPointerException();
    input = input.replace(" "+toReplace+" ", " "+replacement+" ");
    input = input.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("^"+toReplace+" "), replacement+" ");
    input = input.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(" "+toReplace+"$"), " "+replacement);
    //input = input.replaceAll("\\b" + Pattern.quote(toReplace) + "\\b", replacement);
    return input;
}
```

behaves this way when:

```
    input = "test a testtest te[(st string test";
    input = replace(input, toReplace, "REP");
    System.out.println(input);
```

a) `toReplace = test` prints:

```
test a testtest te[(st string test
```

b) `toReplace = te[(st` prints:

```
test a testtest REP string test
```

Thanks,

Comment: What problem you having? What is your expectation and what you getting?

Comment: I have 2 expectations: a) toReplace should we regex safe. b) economy of code (a one line code perhaps).

Comment: What do you mean by regex safe?

Comment: If you don't want to allow regex special characters in your regex pattern, why are you using regex at all? Using user-input strings as regex patterns is a sign that you should rethink your approach.

Answer (score 5):

Use word boundaries `\b` and `Pattern.quote` to escape.

```
return input.replaceAll("\\b" + Pattern.quote(toReplace) + "\\b", replacement);
```

What `\\b` indicates is a zero-width boundary between a word and a non-word character including the very start and very end of the string.

Comment: No need to capture and rewrite `\\b`, they are zero-length.

Comment: Non-capturing? He's put them in parens, making them captured groups.

Comment: @Keppil ah, you mean zero-width, not non-capturing. Fair point.

Comment: Thanks, I have a side question. If I replace input = input.replace("^"+toReplace+" ", " "+replacement+" "); with input = input.replace(Pattern.quote("^"+toReplace+" "), " "+replacement+" "); it does not work for the test case: StringUtils.replace(input, "test", "REP"); input = test a testtest te[(st string. Expected output = REP a testtest te[(st string

Comment: @aryan did you mean to type some more there?

Comment: while StringUtils.replace(input, "te[(st", "REP"); works as expected. I am just trying to understand why.

Comment: @aryan isn't that because `te[(st` contains regex meta characters?  `StringUtils.replace` doesn't support regex as far as I know

Comment: Sorry, StringUtils is my class I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 4):

There is a special regexp code for word boundary - `\b`. That covers your manual handlings of spaces/line endings beginning as well as other cases like punctuation.

There is a method `Pattern.quote()` to quote strings to protect regexp special inside which, as you have suggested, should always be used if the string is arbitrary or might be user-supplied.

So that gives:

```
input.replaceAll("\\b"+Pattern.quote(toReplace)+"\\b", replacement);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\b"+Pattern.quote(toReplace)+"\\b", replacement);
```

\b matches word boundaries, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Use java.util.regex.Pattern.quote to escape special characters.

Comment: Code fails; you'd have to escape the backslashes in your regex.

Comment: Missing \ fixed. Thx for comments.

Comment: you need to Pattern.quote(toReplace) there.

Comment: @aryan ... that's what I meant with "Use java.util.regex.Pattern.quote to escape special characters." - but you're right, it should be in the code too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know about the regex `\b`, which is a zero-width match of a "word boundary".  With it, the guys of your method becomes simply one line:

```
return input.replaceAll("\\b"+Pattern.quote(toReplace)+"\\b", replacement);
```